# Is it possible to count the number of different exceptions mentioned in the logs in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am curious if it is possible to create a dashboard showing the different exceptions and the number of log messages mentioning them in Kibana?

A message qualifies if it is an ERROR or FATAL message and if it matches the following query:

```
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*Exception",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is your mapping like? Typing "*Exception" in search field will do the query you wrote. You can use term aggregation if you have a field like ExceptionType or similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, my grok filter does not do this kind of extra processing. I do not have any field containing just the exception type. Are you saying that in order to achieve what I want I need to elaborate my grok filter and inject  a dedicated field into the documents?

Comment: Can you show an example document ?